# How can I write this algorithm using iteration?

Tags: recursion, iteration

How can I write this algorithm using iteration?

```
function generate(num1:byval) 
     if num1 > 10 then 
          return 10 
     else 
          return num1 + (generate(num1 + 1) DIV 2) 
     endif 
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

So it's not straight forward so I start by doing some grunt work:

```
n    result
11.. 10
10   10
9    9 + 10/2
8    8 + (9 + 10/2)/2
7    7 + (8 + (9 + 10/2)/2)/2
```

This looks like a pattern.. While the recursive version started on the input and went upwards it's easy to see that by starting at 10 and going downwards one can simply update the accumulator by halving the value and adding the current value.

This can easily be implemented using a helper:

```pascal
procedure generate(num : integer) : integer
begin
  generate := generateHelper(10, num, 0)
end


procedure generateHelper(cur : integer, num: integer, acc : integer) : integer
begin
  if cur = num then     
    generateHelper := cur + acc/2;
  else
    generateHelper := generateHelper(cur - 1, num, acc/2 + cur);
end
```

Or by using a loop:

```pascal
procedure generate(num : integer) : integer
var cur, acc : integer;
begin
  for cur := 10 downto cur do
      acc := acc / 2 + cur;
  generate := acc;
end
```

Comment: `function generate(n) { return n > 10 ? 10 : n > 7 ? (17 - n) * n / 2 - 20 : n * 2 + 1 + (n > -2 ? 0 : 1); }`

Comment: @melpomene Nice. Indeed it's so regular that one might find a formula for the sum of any `n` in O(1). That would not qualify as iteration, would it?

Answer (score 1):

If you work out some values for the function…

```
f(10) = 10
f(9) = 9+f(10)/2 = 9+10/2 = 14
f(8) = 8+f(9)/2 = 8+14/2 = 15
…
```

You will get a sense that you could repeatedly apply the same formula to a value in a loop.  You see if you start from 10, you divide by 2 and add 9, then divide by 2 and add 8, and keep going until you reach the number given to the function.  That would look something like this, e.g. in JavaScript:

```
function generate(n) {
  let x = 10;

  for(let i = 10; i > n; i--) {
    x = i - 1 + x / 2;
  }

  return x;
}
```

Comment: `if(n >= 10) return 10;` is redundant.

Comment: @melpomene thanks, I was making edits before I posted and forgot to take that out.